# not able to hit the router in the browser when I hit the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server

- I have a working codebase where they have already setup node proxy and jwt.
- my server  is running at 1010 port
- but when I hit this url `http://localhost:1010/sampletest`
- I am getting an error in the browser screen `Cannot GET /sampletest`
- even I hit this url http://localhost:1010/jump/api/v1 but still I am getting same error
- can you tell me how to fix it or am I missing anthing in the configurations
- providing my index.js and server.js code below

**sports.js**

```or-tag-here
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const mime = require('mime-types');

const router = express.Router();
const ResponseUtil = require('../../utils/ResponseUtil');
const AppConstants = require('../../../constants/AppConstants');

const credentials = require('../../../internals/credentials.json');

const memberGroupingHelper = require('../../helpers/rank/memberGrouping');
const exportHelper = require('../../helpers/rank/rankExportHelper');
const formatExportData = require('../../helpers/rank/formatExportData');

const rankCommonHelper = require('../../helpers/rank/rankCommonHelper');
const rankProvDataHelper = require('../../helpers/group/getProvData');

//const aggregateHelper = require('../../helpers/group/aggregateFilter');

const { rankAggregatelastrsApi } = require('jump-svc-utils');


//router.get('/:searchMode/:lastrSearch', (req, res, next) => {
router.get('/sampletest', (req, res, next) => {


  const { originalUrl } = req;

  //console.log(" originalUrl  ", originalUrl);

  const mode = req.params.searchMode;

  const value = encodeURIComponent(req.params.lastrSearch);


  console.log("document 40--->", mode);
  console.log("for document Testing0--->", mode);





  const url = `/jkjkjk/sdjksdjkjksdjksd/sdklsdlksdklsdkl`;

  axios.get(AppConstants.GET_JWT_TOKEN_URL, {
    auth: {
      username: credentials.auth.racfId, password: credentials.auth.password
    }
  })
    .then((jwtResponse) => {
     // var jwtToken = `Bearer ${jwtResponse.data.jwt}`;
            var jwtToken = `Bearer 787878bjhbnmnmmwqdqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqwqw`;


      axios.get(url, { headers: { "Authorization": jwtToken } })

        .then((response) => {
          console.log("document then0--->", response);
          const file = Buffer.from(response.data.content, 'base64');
          const fileType = mime.contentType(response.data.contentInfo.fileType);
          const fileExtension = response.data.contentInfo.fileType.toLowerCase();
          const fileName = `filename=${response.data.contentInfo.id}.${fileExtension}`;
          res.set('Content-Type', fileType);
          res.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; ${fileName}`);
          res.send(file);
        })


        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("e catch document0--->", e);
          console.log("e.message catch document0--->", e.message);

          console.log("catch document--->", e.response);

          if (e.response) {
            return res.status(e.response.status).send(e.response.data);
          }
          res.status(500).send(e.message || 'Something wrong');
        });
    });


  ResponseUtil.callService(res, url);



});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```or-tag-here
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 1010
const jumpServices = require('./services/jump');
const compression = require('compression');
var BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');



app.use('/jump/api/v1', jumpServices);

app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

//app.use(compress())

// app.use(compression());

// include all the controllers
const controllers = glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, '/controllers/**/*.js'));
console.log("controllers--->", controllers);
controllers.forEach((controllerFileName) => {
  require(controllerFileName)(app); //eslint-disable-line
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Is the double slash in ` http://localhost:1010//jump/api/v1` a typo?

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense yeah its a typo...but still I am getting the error...updated my question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any calls registering your sub Routers with the top level express application.  You should need to call app.use for each of your sub routers.

Comment: Hey I am new to express... can you update my code snippet so confusing :(

Comment: I can refer you to the documentation but updating your code is on you.  There is too much therehttps://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: hey can you you update your code in this sandbox...this is a sample node js code https://codesandbox.io/embed/147w09qvzq?codemirror=1 I looked at the documentation but still hard to understand :(

Comment: Hey I googled but not able to find any sample example...can you provide links of sample example so that I will build it from scratch